# Updating attributes of an other related model in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two entities **Gabarit** and **Local_Gabarit** and i have a foreign key that related those entities called **CodeBarre** which is the primary Key of **Gabarit**. So on my Gabarit Edit Page i don't want to edit **Gabarit** attributes but the related attributes existing in **Local_Gabarit** such as Armoire and Emplacement.
Please, I need your help and Thank you :)

**Gabarit Model:**

```
 public Gabarit()
        {
            this.Demande = new HashSet<Demande>();
            this.Local_Gabarit = new HashSet<Local_Gabarit>();
            this.Mvt_Gabarit = new HashSet<Mvt_Gabarit>();
        }

        public int CodeBarre { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public string Exemplaire { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Produit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Poste { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Demande> Demande { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Local_Gabarit> Local_Gabarit { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Mvt_Gabarit> Mvt_Gabarit { get; set; }
```

**Local_Gabarit Model:**

```
public partial class Local_Gabarit
{
    public int id_local { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Emplacement { get; set; }
    public string Armoire { get; set; }
    public int CodeBarre { get; set; }
    public int id_demande { get; set; }
    public string InOut { get; set; }

    public virtual Demande Demande { get; set; }
    public virtual Gabarit Gabarit { get; set; }
}
```

**GabaritViewModel:**

```
public class GabaritViewModel
{
    public int CodeBarre { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Produit { get; set; }
    public string Exemplaire { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Poste { get; set; }

    public int id_local { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Emplacement { get; set; }
    public string Armoire { get; set; }
}
```

**GabaritsController:**

```
 // GET: Gabarits/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {

            var localrepository = new LocalGabaritRepository(db);
            var dbgabarit = gabaritrepository.GetById(id);
            var req = localrepository.Get(p => p.CodeBarre == dbgabarit.CodeBarre).SingleOrDefault();
            var armoire = req.Armoire;
            var emplacement = req.Emplacement;

            if (dbgabarit != null)
            {
                var gabarit = new GabaritViewModel()
                {
                    CodeBarre = dbgabarit.CodeBarre,
                    Designation = dbgabarit.Designation,
                    Photo = dbgabarit.Photo,
                    Exemplaire = dbgabarit.Exemplaire,
                    Poste=dbgabarit.Poste,
                    Produit=dbgabarit.Produit,
                    Emplacement=emplacement,
                    Armoire=armoire,
                };

                return View(gabarit);
            }
            else
                return HttpNotFound();
        }

        // POST: Gabarits/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit( GabaritViewModel gabarit)
        {
           var  localrepository = new LocalGabaritRepository(db);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              var req= localrepository.Get(p => p.CodeBarre == gabarit.CodeBarre).SingleOrDefault();
              var armoire = req.Armoire;
              var emplacement = req.Emplacement;
              var idl = req.id_local;
              var idd = req.id_demande;
              var InOut = req.InOut;
              var CodeBarre = req.CodeBarre;

              var dblocal = new Local_Gabarit()
              {
                  Emplacement = emplacement,
                  Armoire = armoire,
                  id_local=idl,
                  id_demande=idd,
                  InOut=InOut,
                  CodeBarre=CodeBarre

              };
              localrepository.Update(dblocal);

            }
            return View(gabarit);
        }
```

**Edit.cshtml (Gabarit):**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Gabarit</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CodeBarre)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeBarre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodeBarre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeBarre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" >
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Designation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Designation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Designation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Photo)" width="200" height="200" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Produit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Armoire, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Armoire, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Armoire, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Emplacement, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Emplacement, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Emplacement, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I don't know if i'm in the right way or not but this is what i tried to do.
Thank you.

Comment: This line of code `public virtual ICollection<Local_Gabarit> Local_Gabarit { get; set; }` means you have one-to-many relationship. If is that so you will be editing a list of `Local_Gabarit` with multiple items. Or your model should actually be one-to-one?

Comment: My model should be one-to-many..In Local_Gabarit i have multiple Gabarits.